# Wrong keyboard focus order - a11y

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I have created an application in React.js with satisfying all WCGA accessible guidelines. But currently I'm facing some issues like

1. The keyboard focus always starts from first interactive element (back
   button) regardless of the caret/cursor position in the document.

To understand this issue, I am adding a portion of source code where the user can enter their first name and last name. I have also added a back button on the top left of the same page.
Please find the code below:

```
<section >
  <button onClick={()=>this.goback()>Back</button>
</section>
<section >
        <form className="form-example">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User Details:</legend>
                {this.state.errors && this.state.errors.length?  <section>
                    {this.state.errors}
                </section> : null}
                <section className='input-fields'>
                <label> First Name:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    aria-label='First Name'
                    id = 'name'
                    aria-required="true"
                    onChange={this.onchangeHandler}
                    value={this.state.firstName}
                    name="firstname"
                    />
                </label>
                <label> Last Name:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    aria-label='Last Name'
                    aria-required="true"
                    onChange={this.onchangeHandler}
                    id='lastName'
                    value={this.state.lastName}
                    name="lastName"
                    />
                </label>

                <button type="button" id='submit' onClick={()=>this.submitForm()}>Login</button>
            </section>

            </fieldset>
            </form>
    </section>
```

People with visual impairments can become disoriented when tabbing takes focus someplace unexpected, or when they cannot easily find the content surrounding an interactive element. This means when an user places the cursor at the "first name" field and presses the "tab" button, the focus is going to the back button (which is the first interactive element in the page), but it's expected to go to the "last name" field.

**scenario** 
 - An html page contains multiple interactive elements. A user with some visual disabilities places the cursor in an element in the middle of the page, and presses **tab key** to move the focus to the very next element.

**Issue**
    - The focus is going to the top of the page (first interactive element).

Can anyone suggest a solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you correct syntax for 1st button - You are missing ending bracket } in onClick arrow function. Correct syntax - `<button onClick={()=>this.goback()}>Back</button>`

Comment: Working code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-booth-7jf0n, Hope that helps!!!

Comment: @tarzenchugh, I checked it. but unfortunately it didnt work. If the cursor(only hover,dont click) is on "first name"  field, then the focus should go to "last name" field after tab pressing. currently it goes to back button

Comment: What do you mean (only hover, dont click) - hover has no bearing on focus. Are you expecting behaviour that is not 'normal', i.e. I hover over a box to give it focus or are you just getting confused as someone has added focus indicators on hover making you think an item has focus? hover and focus are separate states. Focus always starts at the top of the page, you *must* click into an input or set focus programatically to change this.

Comment: When I test the sandbox that @tarzenchugh posted by clicking into the "Browser" frame and tabbing, the tab focus order I'm seeing is (1) Back Button, (2) First Name input, (3) Last Name input, (4) Login Button. This is the same order that these elements appear in the code, and this is the expected behavior. To me, this appears to be working as it should. I'm unclear on what behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Josh @GrahamRitchie  , Actually I'm asking about a weird a11y issue. disabled peoples will use keyboard arrow keys to make the screen reader( you can try NVDA screen reader)  to announce each items in the UI. So,  when an user hearing "last name" from the screen reader, he may press tab key by expecting the focus will move to "login" button. But it actually moves to the first interactive element (back button).

Comment: You are confused. This isn't how it works, you don't press tab in a screen reader to access the currently spoken item, you would use `NVDA+shift+numPadSubtract` (defaults) to do this. Generally this is not how someone would consume your content. Also you wouldn't use the arrow keys that often to navigate (in NVDA), instead using sections, headings and plain Tab key (without modifier) depending on what mode you are in (forms, reading etc.) I would suggest watching a couple of videos on how to use a screen reader, they don't take long to learn the basics. **Your code is expected behaviour!**